# There is a easy way to protect a variable to be accesed only by one thread at once?

Tags: java, android, multithreading

i have a variable on my "`SharedPreferences`", that is accesed by two different threads, one in a service, and one in a activity.

There is a easy way to protect this variable to be accesed by two threads at once?

i need to protect this code:

```
            configEditor.putString("mylatitude", ""+currentLocation.getLatitude());
            configEditor.putString("mylongitude", ""+currentLocation.getLongitude());
            configEditor.commit();
```

i tryed with this but doesn't works:

```
Object LOCK = new Object();
                synchronized (LOCK){
                configEditor.putString("mylatitude", ""+currentLocation.getLatitude());
                configEditor.putString("mylongitude", ""+currentLocation.getLongitude());
                configEditor.commit();
                }
```

thanks

Comment: Please add a tag for your question "Java" , this has nothing to do with Android, it is Java related

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure, but I believe using a Handler may be what you need.
Take a look at [this article](http://mindtherobot.com/blog/159/android-guts-intro-to-loopers-and-handlers/), which explains when and how to use them. It also provides some code samples which may be helpful.

Answer (score 6):

```
Object LOCK = new Object();


 synchronized (LOCK) {
     // lines of Java code that has to be thread safe
    }
```

EDIT: edit the code to be exactly for the situation when the code is modifying several variables and it has to be thread-safe. For a single variable (as is in the title of the question) lock the variable itself, you don't need a separate lock for it.

Comment: what? how synchronized? is a method?

Comment: i need to protect this code:        configEditor.putString("mylatitude", ""+currentLocation.getLatitude());
       configEditor.putString("mylongitude", ""+currentLocation.getLongitude());
             configEditor.commit();

Comment: it is a keyword, like "public" , "static" etc., it means that while the code in the {} is being executed, another thread can't use the object which is in the ()

Comment: plz tell me how to protect the code i post in first question, i dont understand how to do it with that

Comment: Object LOCK = new Object(); synchronized (LOCK) { /* Your code */ }

Comment: i dont understand it... please do it with the three lines of code i told in first question

Comment: lol, you are kidding right ?? I pasted you a snippet with a comment "your code here", and you still want me to give you code snippet which you can use ?

Comment: no no mate, im not kidding, im not modifying a simple variable, i am modifing configeditor, that haves variables inside that been modified by put string and commit, then i dont know how to do it with your example, cause this i hope u will edit your first answer with the code

Comment: fine, here is a full code snippet. PLEASE don't tell me again that you cannot use it. I am answering in a general way, that will be easy to understand for the next people who read it

Comment: is this the correct way??? if (currentLocation!=null) {
       //outlat.setText("Latitude: " + currentLocation.getLatitude());
       //outlong.setText("Longitude: " + currentLocation.getLongitude());
       synchronized (configEditor){
       configEditor.putString("mylatitude", ""+currentLocation.getLatitude());
       configEditor.putString("mylongitude", ""+currentLocation.getLongitude());
             configEditor.commit();
       }

Comment: it doesn't works!!! my app is still crashing with the same exception of threads accesing the same variable

Comment: Instead of just copying code somebody pastes, you should really take the time to understand synchronization in Java.  Here's a link to a tutorial on the subject from Sun/Oracle: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/locksync.html

Comment: i use your answer to do my code and doesnt works, im doing bad? please read my first question i edited it with my code... ¿im doing it bad?

Comment: Can't you see that your code is not exactly the same as mine ? It is 3 lines of code so it won't be difficult for you to see what is the difference

Comment: i edit first question with new code.. is that the correct one?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
public class MyClass {
    private final Object lock = new Object();

    public myMethod() {
        ...
        synchronized (lock) {
            // At most one thread is executing this
            // at the same time for this instance
        }
        ...
    }
}
```

The important thing is that the lock object should be an instance (and not local) variable, so that every thread uses the same lock for that particular instance of MyClass. Most of the time you want it to be `final` so that there is no posibility of changing it by mistake.

If you make the lock `static`, then at most one thread will be executing the `synchronized` section, no matter in which instance of MyClass.

**EDIT:**

For your particular case, you can adapt the following idea:

```
public class Service {
    public void doSomethingWithConfigEditor() {
        ConfigEditor configEditor = // get configEditor
        synchronized (configEditor) {
            // something with configEditor
        }            
    }    
}

public class Activity {
    public void doAnotherThingWithConfigEditor() {
        ConfigEditor configEditor = // get configEditor
        synchronized (configEditor) {
            // another thing with configEditor
        }            
    }
}
```

By synchronizing on configEditor, you guarantee that those two blocks of code never execute in parallel on the same instance of ConfigEditor.

Comment: +1   I wouldnt be surprised if he says it fails again where as hes using difference instances of MyClass

Comment: it doesn't help me because i write the variables in a service, with another method, doesn't use myclass. Here i am on a differenct activity, and here i use this clas. No way, i dont understand how to use your method then, different classes, service vs activity writing and reading the file

Answer (score 0):

This is typically done using critical sections aka mutexes. Before accessing the variable, your thread should aquire a lock on the mutex. While the mutex is locked, any attempt to aquire another lock will wait until the previous lock is released. This way, threads will wait for each other when accessing the variable.

Comment: and there is a easy way to do it? without putting a lot of code?

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the `synchronized` block in both locations that access the variable which you are trying to protect.  Protecting it only one of the locations doesn't help.

Comment: it is not possible cause when i acces to write i have to put: configEditor.putString("mylatitude", ""+currentLocation.getLatitude());

Comment: and when i have to read i have to put: settings.getString("mylatitude", null)

Comment: then they are not the same variable :S its very hard

Comment: Then you need to have a global variable that both can lock.  Creating a lock object locally does no good at all.

Comment: i dont understand how to do it, can you write the code example please?

Comment: the threads are in different classes, one is in a service and another in aactivity

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this is in two different threads?  Your service code will only be running in a different thread if you are executing due to someone calling through to your IBinder interface from another process (or another thread in your own process).

Comment: i acces to write in a service: configEditor.putString("mylatitude", ""+currentLocation.getLatitude());

Comment: i acces to read in a different activity: settings.getString("mylatitude", null)